# Jquery code doesn't work with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to make the header paragraph disappear at a certain width (say 1024px width) when the menu button is toggled.
As soon as I add the Jquery code the browser returns an error (ReferenceError: openSide is not defined) that doesn't exist if I comment the Jquery code.
I don't now if Jquery has been written thoroughly, but so far I cannot go through this issue

html:

```
<div id="header">

       <header id="title">
          <h1 style="font-size: 70px; font-weight: 600">The Nest</h1>
          <p style="font-size: 40px">The hostel where your journey should start</p>

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg" id="menu-btn" onclick="openSide()">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span>
          </button>

       </header>

    </div>

    <div id="sidebar">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closeSide()">&times;</a>
        <a href="#">Accomodations</a>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <a href="#">Merchandising</a>
        <a href="#">About us</a>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function openSide() {
document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "350px";
//document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundPosition = "-250px";
document.getElementById("title").style.marginRight = "350px";
//document.getElementById("header").style.background = "linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5))";
}

function closeSide() {
document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "0";
//document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundPosition = "0px";
document.getElementById("title").style.marginRight = "0px";
}

var main = function() {

if (max-width = 1024px) {
$("#menu-btn").click(function() {
   $("#title p").hide();
});
}

}

$(document).ready(main);
```

thx for your help

Comment: why are you mixing inline event handlers and jquery event handlers in the first place?

Comment: Syntax error: `if (max-width = 1024px)`.  Should probably be `if (max-width == '1024px')`.

Comment: I've started first with Javascript to make my side navbar appear and disappear (and it works), but once Jquery has been added, Javascript code doesn't work no more

Comment: `max-width` isn’t a variable and can’t be a variable.

Comment: @Dema Are you getting any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: `Jquery code doesn't work with javascript` - jQuery **IS** javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your using the assignment operator instead of the equal operator. Your code should be:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  // Your condition here
  if (true) {
    $('#menu-btn').click(function() {
      $('#title').hide();
   });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="menu-btn">Hide content</button>
<div id="title">foo</div>
```

Btw, in the code that you posted, the variable `max-width` is not a valid variable name and also you are not defining it.

Comment: `max-width` is not a variable. It can’t be a variable, because that’s not a valid variable name.

Comment: Thx Matìas, I've understood that "max-width" should be a variable (otherwise it doesn't make sense). Why do you think javascript code doesn't work?

Comment: @Dema You can't have `-` in a variable name. Use `max_width` or `maxWidth`.

Comment: @Dema If you put a valid condition it should work fine

Comment: I've set the var of Jquery code properly and now Javascript code works fine. Thx for your help. Now I have to fix all the rest :)